# plot extra circle on a Matlab figure

Tags: matlab, geometry

I'm plotting rose diagrams using Matlab7. And I would like to add an extra red circle on the rose diagram.

```
rose(data,nbins);
hold on
```

I tried the function `pdecirc` but it doesn't work. Anyonce can give me a clue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
% Draw rose
figure
load sunspot.dat  % Contains a 2-column vector named sunspot
rose(sunspot(:,2),12)
hold on

% Draw a red circle
t = 0:.01:2*pi;
plot(2*sin(t)+20,2*cos(t)+20, '--rs','LineWidth',1);
hold off
```